# Is time sharing an illusion?

Tags: time-complexity

I understand that every modern human made computer is being operated by *time sharing operating systems* which allow two or more users running two or more processes at once each, from two different terminals.

Take for example playing two songs at once: One from YouTube and one from MP3; they appear "mixed" but the "particles" of each one are being played alone in a tremendous velocity so to the human mind it appears "mixed" but not really is.

**Is time sharing an illusion?**
Is it true to say that even time sharing operating systems still handle each process alone in **tremendous velocity** so that the time sharing is just an illusion of "present" but is actually only the past and the future so two or more processes can't really be handled by one single processing unit at the exact same time?

Comment: Multi-core processors can run several programs in parallel.

Comment: Also, things are not simple when peripheral devices are involved. I don't know much about the topic, but it may be the case (I don't know if it is) that the CPU during one particle asks the sound device to play something at time $t$, then during the next particle asks to play something else during the same time $t$, the results are mixed and then you hear a true mix of sounds. Also, CPU doesn't even have to participate in the process.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus perhaps instead of CPU I should edit my question to say "SPU" (single processing unit).

Comment: (Just be sure to check whether these cores do have "isolated memory" - can't remember any *homogeneous ones* that don't, didn't check *little/BIG*.)